# How to determine how many shells deep I might be?

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm wondering whether I've called the shell recursively, is there an easy way to find out? Is any solution specific to the shell? I'm using bash.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
echo $SHLVL
```

From the bash manpage:

> SHLVL  Incremented by one each time an
>   instance of bash is started.

Comment: Ah, there it is!

Comment: So I guess checking the parent process ID recursively would be a waste of time, eh?

Comment: Checking the parent process does have the advantage that it'll work for any shell.

Answer (score 6):

One way is to use pstree:

```
$ pstree -h
[...]
├─sshd─┬─sshd───sshd───bash───bash───bash───bash───bash───pstree
│      └─sshd───sshd───bash───bash───bash───bash
[...]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $SHLVL
```

This will catch if you do something like:

```
[sharpestmarble@sandbox ~]$ bash
```

Although that won't catch something like if you SSH into localhost.

```
[sharpestmarble@sandbox ~]$ ssh localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

Also useful: `$BASH_SUBSHELL`

```
$ echo $SHLVL
1
$ (echo $SHLVL)
1
$ echo $BASH_SUBSHELL
0
$ (echo $BASH_SUBSHELL)
1
$ ( (echo $BASH_SUBSHELL) )
2
```